# HLS Live Stream API in Python serving files from the disk

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, http-live-streaming

I have a camera which captures videos and then i use FFMPEG to segment those videos for HTTP Live Streaming and generate an m3u8 file and their corresponsing ts files

I have all the *.ts files and *.m3u8 files created in my local folder and i would like to serve those files to the client using an API

I have created a Flask application in Python

Flask API.

```
@app.route('/videos/<file_name>')
def live_stream(file_name): 
    return send_from_directory("D:\\public", file_name)
```

HTML Code

```
<html>
   <body>
      <video width="400" controls>
         <source src="http://127.0.0.1:5000/videos/toystory.m3u8" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
   </body>
</html>
```

Sample m3u8 file. As you can see there is no End tag since i keep on appending new ts files to this m3u8 file to support live streaming

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:64
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:64.397667,
toystory0.ts
```

Couple of issues that i had:

1. Is there a python library which i can use which provides me a way to serve HLS stream from the files stored on disk
2. Even though the file is sent across as per my fiddler output i don't see the video on the browser

Comment: For your case, [nginx](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_hls_module.html) would be a much more appropriate tool.

Comment: Any HTTP server can handle serving your HLS segments.  No special Python app needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need extra url like `http://127.0.0.1/videos/<video_directory>/<video_segments>/` that will serve segment files. Now your server serve only index file. And you should use [hls.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/) to playback video segments. hls.js send requests for segment files.